# Summarise weekly order data by day SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, distinct

I have a table which contains data like the following:

```
Item       Date      Customer
------------------------------
apple   01/01/2017      a
apple   01/01/2017      a
apple   02/01/2017      b
apple   05/01/2017      c
apple   06/01/2017      b
apple   06/01/2017      d
apple   07/01/2017      c
apple   09/01/2017      a
banana  01/01/2017      b
banana  02/01/2017      a
```

What I need is a summary grouped by day and item of how many UNIQUE customers bought that item in the WEEK of that day (i.e. day +- 3 days), as well as on the day itself.

It should look like this:

```
Item         Date       Weekly Customers   Daily Customers
-----------------------------------------------------------
    apple   01/01/2017         2               1
    apple   02/01/2017         3               1
    apple   05/01/2017         3               1
    apple   06/01/2017         4               2
    apple   07/01/2017         4               1
    apple   09/01/2017         4               1
    banana  01/01/2017         2               1
    banana  02/01/2017         2               1
```

I've managed to summarise by item, day, unique Daily Customers with the following which I think is correct:

```
SELECT 
    item as 'Item', boughtDate as 'Date',
    COUNT(DISTINCT(customer)) as 'Daily Customers'
FROM tbl1 
GROUP BY Item, Date
```

I'm really stumped with how to take each distinct item + day combo and get the total unique customers for the week that day is in (3 days either side of that day) and join it with these results.

I've been playing with some loops and CTEs but I seem to have problems with none of the values being unique in any given field. I am sure there is a simple way of doing this that I am just not thinking of?

Comment: windowing functions

Comment: 2 subqueries and joins. You should have (or create) a table to help determines date that is in the same week.

Comment: I've just had a look at windowing functions @JoePhillips . The description sounded promising but it seems use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause? I was using the over clause to look at the boughtDate but I need to only count distinct customers and a customer can buy multiple times in a day/week.

Comment: @DVT can you elaborate on your idea? Each boughtDate can have 6 other dates associated with it and each of those can have multiple items and customers which I need to summarise. I'm just struggling since there is never any unique key to join on?

Answer (score 0):

aside from parameterizing your query, will this work for your needs?

Change the date to a string representing the date your results represent?  Since the string is fixed in this example, applying max() will not require it as part of the group by clause.

```
SELECT 
      item as 'Item', 
      max( 'Week of 7-11 to 7-17' ) as 'Date',
      COUNT(DISTINCT(customer)) as 'Weekly Customers'
   FROM 
      tbl1
   where 
          boughtDate >= '2017-07-11' 
      and boughtDate < '2017-07-18'
   GROUP BY 
      Item
```

OR...
Were you looking for each individual person +/- 3 days from their purchases which COULD be a continuous rolling time period if a person comes in and buys every 2-3 days.

Comment: I should have mentioned the actual data covers a much longer period of a few months, so I don't want to specify each weekly period in the query itself. Rather the SQL should look at each distinct date in the table, then select all the customer records from that date +-3 days, count the distinct customers and return that total to the table for that date and item.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT 
      item as 'Item', 
      max( 'Week of 7-11 to 7-17' ) as 'Date',
      COUNT(DISTINCT(customer)) as 'Weekly Customers'
   FROM 
      tbl1
   where 
          boughtDate >= '2017-07-11' 
      and boughtDate < '2017-07-18'
   GROUP BY 
      Item`

I would try something like this.